# How to check if multiple html select have same value

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 select input in a form, and for the validation i want to make sure they don't have the same value. the select options are same, but a select should have 1 individual option selected. This is the code i have presently thats not working

```
var bk1 = document.getElementById("block1").value;
var bk2 = document.getElementById("block2").value;
var bk3 = document.getElementById("block3").value;
var bk4 = document.getElementById("block4").value;
var bk5 = document.getElementById("block5").value;
var res = true;      
    if(bk1 !=== bk2 && bk1 !=== bk3 && bk1 !=== bk4 && bk1 !=== bk5)
    {
        res = true;
    }else
    {
        res = false;
    }        
    if(bk2!===bk1 && bk2 !===bk3 && bk2!===bk4 && bk2!===bk5)
    {
        res = true;
    }else
    {
        res = false;
    }        
    if(bk3!===bk2 && bk3 !===bk1 && bk3!===bk4 && bk3!===bk5)
    {
        res = true;
    }
    else
    {
        res = false;
    }       
    if(bk4!===bk2 && bk4 !===bk3 && bk4!===bk1 && bk4!===bk5)
    {
        res = true;
    }
    else
    {
        res = false;
    }       
    if(bk5!===bk2 && bk5 !===bk3 && bk5!===bk4 && bk5!===bk1)
    {
        res = true;
    }else
    {
        res = false;
    }     
   if(res === true)
   {
    alert("yes");
    document.block_form.submit();
   }else
   {
      alert("wrong");
      document.getElementById("block_error").value = "Multiple blocks have same selected option";
   }
```

Comment: I would put the variables in an array, loop trough that array andsee if you have duplicates. And also.. you are using `!===` it should be `!==` or `!=`.

Comment: Why do you need 5 if-else conditions to verify unique ness. One would be enough.

Comment: the select boxes are for customisation. a page has several functions arranged in blocks. the user is supposed to be able to re-arrange the blocks as they wish. And to make it as simple as possible, so i went with using select. so for block 1, the user has the list of blocks to select, also for block 2 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create array of values;
2. Check array for duplicated values.

For example:

```
var bk1 = document.getElementById("block1").value;
var bk2 = document.getElementById("block2").value;
var bk3 = document.getElementById("block3").value;
var bk4 = document.getElementById("block4").value;
var bk5 = document.getElementById("block5").value;

var test = [bk1, bk2, bk3, bk4, bk5];
var res = true; 
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { 
  if (test.indexOf(test[i], i + 1) >= 0) {
    res = false; 
    break;
  } 
}

if(res){
    alert("yes");
    document.block_form.submit();
}else{
  alert("wrong");
  document.getElementById("block_error").value = "Multiple blocks have same selected option";
}
```

Comment: Could you provide example of values? I tried different cases and all the time my piece of code sets "res" variable to "false" if there is 2 duplicated values

Comment: options: assignment, section, lesson, users, moderators

Comment: I modified the answer to show the whole code. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Having a loop over array of values sounds better but just in case you wanna stick to your own method:

```
var bk1 = document.getElementById("block1").value;
var bk2 = document.getElementById("block2").value;
var bk3 = document.getElementById("block3").value;
var bk4 = document.getElementById("block4").value;
var bk5 = document.getElementById("block5").value;

var res = true;
if(bk1 == bk2 || bk1 == bk3 || bk1 == bk4 || bk1 == bk5 || 
    bk2 == bk3 || bk2 == bk4 || bk2 == bk5 ||
    bk3 == bk4 || bk3 == bk5 ||
    bk4 == bk5){

    res = false;
}


if(res){
    alert("yes");
    document.block_form.submit();
}else{
  alert("wrong");
  document.getElementById("block_error").value = "Multiple blocks have same selected option";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sweet code instead.

```
var arr= [], res=true;
    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        var curVal = document.getElementById("block"+i).value;
        if(arr.indexOf(curVal)!==1) {res=false; break;}
        else arr.push(curVal);
    }


 if(res)
  {
    alert("yes");
    document.block_form.submit();

  }
 else
  {
      alert("wrong");
      document.getElementById("block_error").value = "Multiple blocks have same selected option";
  }
```

Comment: keep getting the alert for wrong, even when they don't have the same selected options

Answer (score 0):

Try this js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/um2ffuqd/

do note that:

```
if ((bk1 !== bk2 && bk1 !== bk3 && bk1 !== bk4 && bk1 !== bk5) 
&& (bk2 !== bk3 && bk2 !== bk4 && bk2 !== bk5) 
&& (bk3 !== bk4 && bk3 !== bk5) 
&& (bk4 !== bk5)) {
    res = true;

} else {
    res = false;
}
```

is incredibely messy, as many other posters here have said you really should use a loop. I tried to stick to you code as much as possible though.

Comment: suggest a loop please

Comment: updated my fiddle with an easy loop that runs over all your elements. http://jsfiddle.net/um2ffuqd/1/
the reason we tell you to use a loop is that adding elements are a lot easier. If you want two more elements there you'll need A LOT more if statements immediately. Working with code that allows for flexible sizes will save you a lot of headache later on.

Answer (score 0):

Or the functional way

```
var bk1 = document.getElementById("block1").value;
var bk2 = document.getElementById("block2").value;
var bk3 = document.getElementById("block3").value;
var bk4 = document.getElementById("block4").value;
var bk5 = document.getElementById("block5").value;

var map = {};

var res = [bk1, bk2, bk3, bk4, bk5].reduce( function (val, e) {
  if (map.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
    return val+1;
  } else {
    map[e] = 1;
    return val;
  }
}, 0);


if (res <= 0) {
  alert("yes");
  document.block_form.submit();
} else {
  alert("wrong");
  document.getElementById("block_error").value = "Multiple blocks have same selected option";
}
```